# scp to Docker Container that is on Remote Host

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am running two AWS EC2 Ubuntu instances in separate regions (Ireland and London). A Docker container is running on each instance.

An established IPSec connection exists:

```
root@ip-10-0-1-178:/mnt# ipsec status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
Ireland-to-London[2]: ESTABLISHED 37 seconds ago, 
172.17.0.1[34.X.X.X]...35.X.X.X[35.X.X.X]
```

Here are some IP's for each:

```
Ireland  
Public IP: 34.X.X.X
Private IP: 10.0.1.178
VPC CIDR Block: 10.0.0.0/16
```

```
London  
Public IP: 35.X.X.X
Private IP: 10.10.1.187
VPC CIDR Block: 10.10.0.0/16
```

```
Docker(same for both)
Public IP: 172.17.0.1
VPC CIDR Block: 172.17.0.0/16
Ports open: 500 and 4500
```

I cannot figure out how to transfer files using scp from a Docker container on one instance to the Docker container on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your docker image has port 22 mapped to 500/4500 so you should be able to use

```
scp -P YOUR_PORT file USERNAME@AWS_IP:/file
```

You can also use docker cp to copy the file to the host machine, then scp to the other machine and then use docker cp to copy to docker image as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

List of things you need to do.

1. Enable ssh ports(e.g 22) on both containers.
2. `EXPOSE` / forward the container ports to the host machine ports(e.g. 2200:22) on both machines.
3. Open the forwarded ports on the host machines in firewall.
4. Now `scp -P 2200 localfile.txt <london_user>@<london_public_ip>:<remote path>`.
5. I ignored the part were you configure password, or key based communication, there are already many resources on that.

Comment: So I am using `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT`
`sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port 500`

Comment: Then I try `ufw allow 500/tcp` on host and it still hangs

Comment: then I think the ssh server is not installed on your container, use [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd/), it has all ssh configs backed in. See its *RUN EXAMPLE*.
Also `docker port test_sshd 22` will tell you which port its forwarded to, then you can simply open that port on your host machine using `ufw allow <port>/tcp`.

Comment: Using the command `docker run -d --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --name test -P -itv ~:/mnt/ test bash` followed by docker port test 22, I get `0.0.0.0:32768` and allow it. The PORTS column running `docker container ls -a` reads `0.0.0.0:32768->22/tcp`. I updated above commands to reflect this. At this point, I may start backtracking and have been looking at my connection. I am pretty sure I should be able to ping the other other public ip from Docker with an installed connection, right? Do you think having the Docker containers on an identical subnet despite being on different hosts could mess it up? Thx